# Cascade delete performance drop on bigger datasets, can this be caused by lack of indexing?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, indexing, cascade

I'm writing some code that has to cascade delete records in a certain database, and I noticed a drop in performance as the database has more records in it. When I just fill the database it doesn't seem like there is a big drop in performance between the start of the filling and right at the end, yet when I do a cascade delete performance goes down with a bigger database. I'm assuming that it would need to make a lot of joins for the cascade to find all the related records in other tables, which causes it to slow down on bigger datasets. But when I just add a record, wouldn't it also have to test for already existing primary keys and other unique constraints and wouldn't this also have to be slower in bigger datasets, or is this so incredibly fast compared to the delete process that it's hard to notice a performace drop when you're just filling a database? Or are the cascades just slow because I didn't specifically index the tables that it cascades to?

So secondly, would indexing the tables it cascades to speed up the cascading if those tables already have a generated id as primary key? In a more general sense: are primary keys automatically indexed?

Comment: How are you cascade deleting?  Using Hibernate .delete(), some HQL?  Straight SQL through JDBC?

Comment: Hibernate .delete(), using cascade = CascadeType.ALL in the hibernate annotations for the fields in the domain model that I'm cascade deleting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm assuming that it would need to make a lot of joins for the cascade to find all the related records in other tables, which causes it to slow down on bigger datasets.

Don't assume. Turn up Hibernate's logging (specifically the logger for `org.hibernate.SQL`) to see *exactly* which SQL statements Hibernate executes. Then make decisions and take actions from facts, instead of assumptions.

> In a more general sense: are primary keys automatically indexed?

Yes.

Comment: Ok, you're totally right, sorry for assuming :$ I guess I was just being lazy. I checked the hibernate logs and indeed it is showing lots and lots of joins to first retreive the related domain objects, and then one by one deleting them. And to the second answer: thanks, I had my suspicions already because the slowdown seemed to have approximately a log(n) relation, but this confirms it. (I know it's not this black and white, but as I said: approximately)